# How to import a group of components for use as HTML tags - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am redesigning my app as to be more modular with the UI side of things, separating things out to have:

- App header
- Nav panel to the left
- Main content to the right of the nav panel

I have managed to work out how to import a single component into the Angular way of things, importing the component into the `app.module.ts` and setting it in the `declarations` area. This way I can simply call  from the HTML and have my app header appear!

However I am having difficulty when trying to do a batch of these at once...

I am seeing an error message such as:

> Error: Unexpected module 'ComponentExportModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

**app.module.ts**

```
//More imports are above...
import {ComponentExportModule} from '../UI-Components/component-export.module';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    //Imports are here
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ComponentExportModule
  ],
  providers:[
    //Stuff is here
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**component-export.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {AppHeaderComponent} from './app-header.component';
import {PageContentComponent} from './page-content.component';
import {SideNavComponent} from './side-nav.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppHeaderComponent,
    PageContentComponent,
    SideNavLinkListComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AppHeaderComponent,
    PageContentComponent,
    SideNavComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentExportModule {}
```

I am then wanting to utilise my components in the usual way within the `app.module.html` file such as:

```
<app-header/>
<nav-bar/>
<page-content/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your app.module.ts is wrong. ComponentExportModule needs to be added to the imports array in your app.module.ts, not declared. Modules are always imported. Components, directives, and pipes are declared.

Also when you add the shared components to your apps template (app.component.html) you will want to use the standard element notation such as: `<app-header></app-header>` instead of `</app-header>` as only void and foreign elements can be self closed

Answer (score 0):

Also when you add the shared components to your apps template (app.component.html) you will want to use the standard element notation such as:  instead of  as only void and foreign elements can be self closed ->correct solution